# Show that $q$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers

> Let q be a positive integer such that $q \geq 2$ and such that for any
>   integers $a$ and $b$, if $q|ab$ then $q|a$ or $q|b$.Show that $q$ is a prime
>   number.

It will probably be proved by contradiction, so I assumed $q$ is a prime, i.e $q=xy$ where $x$ and $y$ are some positive integers and not equal to $1$ or $q$, and tried to a contradiction but I couldn't figure out how to proceed from here.

Comment: Contradiction works...if $q$ is not a prime then $q=ab$ for $1<a,b<q$.  Clearly $q$ does not divide either factor.

Comment: If $q=xy$, where $xy$ are not equal to $1$ or $q$, then isn't that a contradiction, because of course $q$  doesn't divide either $x$ or $y$? (it is larger than both of them). So if $x,y$ take the place of $a,b$ in the yellow box then you have a contradiction.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг with that logic, 6 is also a prime number

Comment: But $6 = 2*3$, whereas $6 \nmid 2$ and $6 \nmid 3$! So it does not hold true that for every pair of numbers $a,b$, $6 |ab$ implies $6|a$ or $6|b$. Let us sort out this confusion quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that this can be proven via contradiction. If $q$ is *not* a prime, then we can find two integers $x, y > 1$ such that $q = xy$. But this means $q|xy$, so by our assumption we have $q|x$ or $q|y$. But neither of these can be true, since $x = \frac{q}{y} < q$ by the assumption $y > 1$ resp. $y = \frac{q}{x} < q$ by the assumption $x > 1$.

Comment: I did not understand why they can not be true quietly ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: :D "But neither of these can be true, since x=py<p
x
=
p
y
<
p
 by the assumption y>1
y
>
1
 resp. y=px<p
y
=
p
x
<
p
 by the assumption x>1
x
>
1
." What do you mean by that ?

Comment: We have $x > 1$, so this means $y = \frac{q}{x} < q$. But this implies that $q$ does not divide $y$, since a divisor of a positive integer can't be greater than the integer itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess my brain is stuck, but if $x > 1$, then y < q, so I still can't  see the point.

Comment: $y < q$ implies that $q$ is not a divisor of $y$. Similarly, $q$ is also not a divisor of $x$. This is a contradiction to the assumption that $q|x$ or $q|y$ must hold.

Comment: yes, but it also holds for $6=2*3$ ?

Comment: And $6$ is also not a prime number. Please take your time to think precisely about the proof before you post further comments.

Comment: After a good sleep, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $q$ is composite. Then you can write $q=nk$ for some $n,k\geq2$. Clearly $q|nk$ as every natural number divides itself, which implies by hypothesis that $q|n$ or $q|k$. In particular $q\leq n$ or $q\leq k$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: what do you mean by "composite" ?

Comment: ["Composite"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) means "not a prime number nor $1$".